# My PSU for my PC buzzed when plugged in, caused a power short, now won't turn on

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, power

My PC was working fine yesterday.

I installed a fan controller today. After installation, I went to plug the computer in and when I did the PSU made a buzz, then the power in the room went off and I had to turn it back on at the circuit board for the house.

While the PC is plugged in now there are lights on the MB & GPU. When I switch it on it makes the usual click sound, however, no fans come on (including the PSU).

I have no idea if the problem is with the PSU or MB since The lights come on but for that to be the case obviously it means the PSU is outputting some power.

I've ordered a new PSU as that is probably the best-case scenario.

What is the likelihood that the CPU/MB/HDD's have fried?

Comment: An error connecting the fan, or a ground short caused by an inexact installation of the fan shorted out the PSU and caused damaged.  That is most likely (greater than 80%) the problem.

Comment: Hopefully, a new PSU will solve the issue, otherwise, you might have to replace your motherboard and possibly your CPU depending on the damage caused by the PSU.  Once installed a CPU is connected to all the power that runs through a motherboard and is connected to the PSU.

Answer (score 2):

A fan controller is likely to be taking its supply from 12v rail of the PSU. On a molex connector, this is the yellow wire. Like all voltage rails, if this rail shorts to ground, in order to prevent more damage, the PSU has an internal over current detection on each voltage rail regulator on each of the voltage rails. Any one of these trip, and the PSU will turn itself off to protect itself from excessive current draw. This trip in modern PSUs is often a resetable trip which can be reset by fulling removing the AC cord, removing the short (ie the original fault), waiting 10secs and then reapplying AC power.

NOTE: a ATX PSU will not power on, unless a pin called the PS_ON pin is pulled to ground. You can fake this when not plugged into your motherboard with the so called paper clip method.

An ATX PSU outputs 12v, 5v, 3v3, 5vSB (ie 5v standby). 5vSB is always outputted by a PSU even when it is not turned on. It achieves this with a separate transformer to generate this 5vSB which motherboards need in addition to the electronics in the PSU itself. A motherboard meanwhile has further regulators which monitor these rails and generate further smaller voltages eg 1v2, 1v5 to DIMMS, when all the rails are up.

The lights on your motherboard are likely due to 5vSB still being outputted by the PSU. Some motherboards show 5vSB being delivered to the motherboard via the ATX connector with a LED on the motherboard as most PSUs do not have LEDs.

Hence, it is possible that your PSU is not blown. Just remove the fan controller, then remove the AC cord, wait 10secs and then plug it back in and see if you PC powers up again.

If it does not, its more than likely the PSU is blown - but its 5vSB is still working. No good to you though.

The only way the motherboard has blown is if the fan controller short managed to sink its current via a component on your motherboard as the fan controller wires perhaps touched something on your motherboard. If this did not happen, there is no way the fault within the fan controller could have sunk its current into the motherboard as current always finds the easiest path to ground - back via the fan controller's PSU connector. !

The thing to be careful on, when the new PSU turns up, DO NOT use the fan controller. Plug the new PSU into the motherboard first. If the Fan controller has a fault on it, you don't want to blow up the new PSU as well. Definitely visually inspect the fan controller to see if it a blown, smell it for burn components, look for bad solder joints or loose wires. Do not use it if it is bust.

To further check, use a Digital volt meter in continuity mode or resistance mode, to check for a short between the 12v to ground and 5v to ground. This should measure a high resistance value and not a dead short ie 0 Ohms. If it does... then that is what cause the PSU to trip / fail. :)

As a FYI, you can buy an inexpensive ATX PSU Tester dongle from ebay. These test all of the PSU voltage rails without needing to plug into an expensive motherboard and test the rise time of PSGOOD which is a signal from the PSU that says all its rails are in regulation.

Hope the above helps and good hunting.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to write a detailed explanation of what was happening. Fortunately it was just the PSU which suffered the damage. The new PSU is working fine as well as the fan controller. Removing the AC cord for 10 seconds with the older one did not resolve the issue, but is useful to know. 

Thanks again!